# Using Dynamic flashVars with HTML5

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, flash

**Hello all, i have a theoretical question.**

With flash you can dynamically load flashvars to a video or audio flashobject.
But:  I would already have a flash video which loads the flashvars like that. But i want to create html5 code (either audio/video) around it. Can i use the flash vars outside of the element/flash object?

Like loading the flash source (mp3) also to the HTML5 audio element, which surrounds the flash element?

**To make it more visual:**

- HTML(5) Page.

Contains a flash object, nested within a HTML5 audio/video element.

- C# page.

Dynamically loads the flashvars & params to the flash object. For example mp3source.

**Problem:**
Can i also load the mp3source flashvar/param to the HTML5 video/audio in some way?

To load the vars i would use htmlgenericcontrols. If someone has an idea about how/if i could create something like this... Please share it! :)

**Thanks for the answers!**

**PS: Some Code** (!Not working, just to give you a clue!)

C# Param

```
var mp3param = new HtmlGenericControl("param");
mp3param.Attributes.Add("name", "thevars");
var thevars= "mp3=" + src;
```

HTML Output

```
<audio id="htmlaudio" controls="">
    <source src="thisshouldbetheflashmp3source" type="audio/mpeg">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="audioplayer.swf" width="xx" height="xx" id="flashaudio" style="visibility: visible;">
    <param name="thevars" value="mp3=Theflashmp3sourcethatdoesworkbutshouldalsobeusedinhtmlaudio">
</object>
</audio>
```

Comment: Do you just want to load it once from the code behind?

Comment: Its just loaded once. When you start the page the flash & audio object are loaded, en the flash needs to give the source param or something to the HTML5 element. If possible :)

Comment: So when loaded the flash immediatly gets its params and vars.

Comment: Post your flash object HTML markup. You can load dynamic value with asp.net inline code block.

Comment: Its theoretical, so i dont have any code :) I will quickly write something to make things a bit more clear,

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume, this is your object tag

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="<%=MovieName%>"/>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<%=MovieName%>" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="<%=MovieName%>"/>
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

You can now create a property in the code behind to grab the data dynamically. Sample code below

```
public string MovieName{
    get { return "Movie_name.swf"; }
}
```

Comment: hmm, i added some code. Maybe its clearer now. I think the easiest way is to dynamically set the src from the html5 video, hmm... Thanks for the help anyway! Got a new clue to figure this out!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but this will definitely work. I have this code working in so many places.

Comment: thats true, but i mean that it wont work in the example im making. Im not looking for workarounds, but more like an answer to the idea if its possible to give the flash audiosource to the HTML5 video in some way. Because what if you cant change the aspx page? Or dont know the ID of the elements because its generated? 
Thats more what im thinking about :)